# What is the truffle command to send token and check balance of token?

Tags: truffle

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract Token {

  string public name;
  string public symbol;
  uint8 public decimals;

  // address public owner;

  mapping (address => uint) balances;

  event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

  function Token(uint256 _supply, string _name, string _symbol, uint8 _decimals) {
    balances[msg.sender] = 10000;
   //  owner=msg.sender;

  }

  function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) returns(bool sufficient) {
    if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;
    balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
    balances[receiver] += amount;
    Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);

    return true;
  }
  function getBalance(address addr) returns(uint) {
    return balances[addr];
  }
}
```

Comment: You may find https://hackernoon.com/how-to-create-a-token-factory-with-ethereum-part-1-85e84d1f38fc#.zduynwlmc useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var token = Token.deployed();
var receiver = "0x123";
var amount = 1;
token.sendCoin(receiver, amount).then(function(txn) {
  console.log("txn hash", txn);
});
```

.... where Token.deployed() was established with `$ truffle migrate`.

Wait for mining, then ...

```
token.balance.call(receiver).then(function(balance) {
  console.log("balance", balance);
});
```

Hope I didn't flub the syntax.

Comment: right ... need to close it. updated the snippets.

Comment: now it is showing ...      :token.sendCoin is not a function ...   what to do now??

Comment: You should deploy the contact with $ truffle migrate --reset. Start the truffle console with $ truffle console. Then, > Token.deployed(). You should see the function or something isn't right. See above for var token = ...

Comment: call() undefined showing

Comment: I flubbed it. It's contact.function.call ... so token.balance.call() would be my guess. Corrected my answer.